QGIS Plugin: Create dynamic comboboxes
I am creating a QGIS Plugin, in which the user can rename columns to specfied names depending on a certain policy.
In the image you can see, that the user selects a layer in QGIS which field names will then populate a mFieldCombobox ('actual name') and in a second Combobox the user is provided with a list of names, defined in the plugin (and depending on the chosen policy).
However, the amount of columns in the layer, which should be renamed, depends on the needs of the user and so I want him/her to be able to add as much comboboxes ('actual name' and 'rename to') as needed. For this I added the '+'-button, which, when pressed, should generate a new 'actual name'-mFieldCombobox and a new 'rename to'-combobox.
Is this possible, and if so, how?
Any help would be very welcome!
My code so far:
    def run(self):
        """Run method that performs all the real work"""

        # Create the dialog with elements (after translation) and keep reference
        # Only create GUI ONCE in callback, so that it will only load when the plugin is started
        if self.first_start == True:
            self.first_start = False
            self.dlg = ReformatToLKNamesDialog()

            # Populate Richtlinien Combobox mit Richtliniennamen
            self.populateRichtinie()

            # Get value from Richtlinie
            self.selected_RL = self.dlg.Richtlinie.currentText()
            self.dlg.Richtlinie.currentTextChanged.connect(self.populateRLS19)

            # Update the combobox with the field names
            self.dlg.LayerName.layerChanged.connect(self.updateFields)

        # show the dialog
        self.dlg.show()

        # Run the dialog event loop
        result = self.dlg.exec_()
        print(type(result))
        # See if OK was pressed
        if result:
            # Write here your code which should run when you hit the button 'OK'
            pass

    def printRL(self):
        self.selected_RL = self.dlg.Richtlinie.currentText()
        if self.selected_RL:
            print(self.dlg.Richtlinie.currentText())

    def updateFields(self):
        self.dlg.mFieldComboBox.clear()
        selectedLayer = self.dlg.LayerName.currentLayer()
        if selectedLayer:
            self.dlg.mFieldComboBox.setLayer(selectedLayer)
   
    def populateRichtinie(self):
        richtlinien = ['RLS-19', 'BUB', 'RLS-90'] # may be added: 'All'
        print(richtlinien)
        self.dlg.Richtlinie.addItems([item for item in richtlinien])


    def populateRLS19(self):
        self.dlg.LKName.clear()
        selectedRichtlinie = self.dlg.Richtlinie.currentText()
        rlkurz = {'st':'sr', 'b':'ra', 'ls':'la'}
        selctedRL_kurzel = rlkurz[selectedRichtlinie]
        print(selctedRL_kurzel)
        rl_kuerzel = [
'list', 'of', 'names']

        rl_f = [selctedRL_kurzel+kuerzel for kuerzel in rl_kuerzel]
        self.dlg.LKName.addItems([item for item in rl_f])




This code should help:
class FieldChanger:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cmbPairList = []  # make cmb accesible as an attribute e.g. for reading values
        self.makeUI()
        self.window.exec()
    
    def makeUI(self):
        """example UI"""

        self.window = QDialog()
        self.mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        
        # press this button to add comboboxes
        self.btn_add = QPushButton('Add Combobox Pair')
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.btn_add)
        self.btn_add.clicked.connect(self.addCMBPair)

        # press this button to read data from comboboxes in dialog
        self.btn_finished = QPushButton('Done')
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.btn_finished)
        self.btn_finished.clicked.connect(self.readSelection)

        self.window.setLayout(self.mainLayout)


    def addCMBPair(self):
        # whenever the add button is clicked ...
        subLayout = QHBoxLayout()  # ... create a horizontal layout

        cmb_left = QComboBox()  # combobox for current field name
        cmb_left.addItem('aFieldNameFromALayer')
        cmb_left.addItem('anotherFieldNameFromALayer')
        subLayout.addWidget(cmb_left)  # add the combobox to the layout 
        
        cmb_right = QComboBox()  # for the new field name
        cmb_right.addItem('aNewName')
        cmb_right.addItem('bNewName')
        subLayout.addWidget(cmb_right) 
        
        self.cmbPairList.append([cmb_left, cmb_right])  # add the boxes to the list (or a dictionary or whatever)
        
        self.mainLayout.addLayout(subLayout)  # and add the sublayout (which contains the comboboxes) to the main layout
    
    def readSelection(self):
        # example for how to get the values from the comboboxes
        for old, new in self.cmbPairList:
            print(old.currentText(), new.currentText())

a = FieldChanger()


Thanks for your answer. It could use some more explanations. Please [edit] it to add more details.
